# CSS Body height: 100% Not Working in Blackberry

Tags: html, css, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

For some strange reason, I could not get my body height to stretch to 100% on BlackBerry phone. It works fine in the Ripple Emulator but on the actual device.

This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="x-blackberry-defaultHoverEffect" content="false" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user- 
scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bbui-0.9.3.css" />-->
<script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css file: layout.css

```
.html
{
  height: 100%;
}
body
{
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I have already set html tag and body tag height to 100% but no use. Anyone has any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes like `height:100%; min-height:100%`. don’t work for blackberry.

So here is the fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.body.style.height = screen.height + ‘px’;
});
```

Add this to javascript file

Comment: Correct - the webview (named BrowserField) doesn't like 100% height (it does like 100% width).  It does recognize fixed unit heights though, as sureshuninvers has indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a typo in your question, but it's suppose to be html not .html as such:

```
html
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

If this does not work for you, try using fixed positioning. This works great for mobile apps (I use this for BB10 and PlayBook development):

```
html,body{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```